# How to make a page that can display link previews with php?

Tags: php, web

### Hello i want to know how i can make a publications page. so this is what i want to know

- How to submit a link and show it on the page
- Make a preview of the link
- links can stack up on the website publications page
- And i want to know how i can make this as easy as possible.

Here is some source code that i have but it doesn't do what i want it to do

```php
<?php
function getSiteOG( $url, $specificTags=0 ){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $res['title'] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $m){
        $tag = $m->getAttribute('name') ?: $m->getAttribute('property');
        if(in_array($tag,['description','keywords']) || strpos($tag,'og:')===0) $res[str_replace('og:','',$tag)] = $m->getAttribute('content');
    }
    return $specificTags? array_intersect_key( $res, array_flip($specificTags) ) : $res;
}
if(isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url']!=''){
  $url = $_GET['url'];
  if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
      $og_details = getSiteOG($url);
  } else {
      echo("Not a valid URL");
  }
}
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="debug-form">
    <form action="" method="get">
      <label>URL</label>
      <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control">
    </form>
  </div>
<br>
  <?php if(isset($og_details) && $og_details){?>
    <div class="debug-box" onclick="openLink(this);" data-link="<?php echo $_GET['url'];?>">
      <img src="<?php echo @$og_details['image'];?>" width="100%">
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <p><strong><?php echo @$og_details['title'];?></strong></p>
        <p class="description"><?php echo @$og_details['description'];?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<script>
  function openLink(source){
    openInNewTab(source.getAttribute('data-link'));
  }
  function openInNewTab(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When asking a question, please stick with _one_ question per post. You also need to explain where you're actually stuck (we need to know exactly what part you're struggling with. in detail). You also need to explain what the posted code actually does and what you expect it to do (again, details). You also need to give us a proper explanation of what you mean by "preview link". It's usually not constructive to just post code and expect us to assume from that.

Comment: i understand. What i meant was that i want to make a publications page and when i put a link in an input form it should be shown on the publications page.

Comment: And what the code does is that it lets you put a link and when you press enter it shows but when i put another link in the input form the previous link preview just goes away from the page i want to be able to stack them on the page and show them on it.

Comment: If the issue is that you want to stack them, then use Ajax to call your PHP code and append the result to the container with the results using JS. If you just have a normal form submission, the page will reload, clear the previous result and only show the new.